# Image retrieving failed with laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to store and show image for my app. Image storing properly but failed to show.
First I created symbolic link using command: `php artisan storage:link`
config/filesystem.php look like:

```
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],
    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

to store image:

```
 if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
{
    $path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars'); 
    //$path=avatars/generated_image_name.extension
    $user->avatar=$path;
    $user->save();
}
//image storing under: (../storage/app/avatars)
```

to display image to view:

```
 <img src="storage/{{$user->avatar}}"
      alt="no image!!"
      class="img-circle" 
      style="width:150px;height:150px;">
```

tried `src="storage/app/{{$user->avatar}}"` & `src="{{$user->avatar}}"`
but can't fetch image. Don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try to use this 
<img src="<?php echo base_path('storage/app/').$user->avatar; ?>" />
Hope it will help

Comment: No its not working...

Comment: do Inspect Element in browser and see, what path actually you are getting in img src. and let me know!

Comment: ```src="/home/xxx/Desktop/dev/app/storage/app/avatars/v53v6htaQfFErmNJ2t7HcHVVabpjR002bVxOcjJT.jpeg"```

Comment: What does `{{$user->avatar}}` display on your blade template?

Comment: Try this. <img src="<?php echo 'storage/app/'.$user->avatar; ?>" />
Make sure $user->avatar is getting perfect path or not.

Comment: $user->avatar=```avatars/v53v6htaQfFErmNJ2t7HcHVVabpjR002bVxOcjJT.jpeg ```@whoacowboy

Comment: Simple solutions for your problem is store your images in public/images directory and retrive it. 
<img src="<?php echo '/images/image.jpg'; ?>" >
It works!

Answer (score 0):

Hate to be that guy, but have you read the docs. You need to create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

> ## [The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk)
>
> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly
>   accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and
>   stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible
>   from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage`
>   to `storage/app/public`. This convention will keep your publicly
>   accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across
>   deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like
>   [Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/).
>
> To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan
>   command:
>
> ```
> php artisan storage:link
> ```

## Edit

Again I would check out the docs or maybe read them :).

I think your default storage is `local` and not `public`. In `config/filesystems.php` look at the default driver.

[Storing Files](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#storing-files) > File Uploads > Specifying A Disk

or try something like this.

```
if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
{
    $path = $request->file('avatar')->store(
      'avatars/'.$request->user()->id, 'public'
    ); 
    //$path=avatars/generated_image_name.extension
    $user->avatar=$path;
    $user->save();
}
```

Comment: Suggestion from my side store your image in public/images directory and when you retrieve write. 
<img src="<?php echo 'images/'.$user->avatar; ?>" />